# Laravel Docker image works locally, not on Clound Run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I've created a Dockerfile that successfully runs my Laravel 8 application locally. This is the content of the Dockerfile, located in my Laravel project root:

```
FROM webdevops/php-nginx:8.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN chmod 777 -R ./storage
ENV WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/app/public
RUN composer install
```

I built the image and ran it locally:

```
docker build . -t gcr.io/my-project/my-image
docker run -p 5000:80 gcr.io/my-project/my-image
```

The container starts and the application runs as expected. No problems. If I shell into the container, I can see the ports that nginx is listening on:

```
> netstat -nlp | grep nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      49/nginx -g daemon
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      49/nginx -g daemon
```

As you can see the container is listening on port 80 of all network interfaces (0.0.0.0). This conforms with the CloudRun documentation and their troubleshooting guide:

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#port

> A common issue is to forget to listen for incoming requests, or to
> listen for incoming requests on the wrong port.
>
> As documented in the container runtime contract, your container must
> listen for incoming requests on the port that is defined by Cloud Run
> and provided in the PORT environment variable.
>
> If your container fails to listen on the expected port, the revision
> health check will fail, the revision will be in an error state and the
> traffic will not be routed to it.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#listen_address

> A common reason for Cloud Run services failing to start is that the
> server process inside the container is configured to listen on the
> localhost (127.0.0.1) address. This refers to the loopback network
> interface, which is not accessible from outside the container and
> therefore Cloud Run health check cannot be performed, causing the
> service deployment failure.
>
> To solve this, configure your application to start the HTTP server to
> listen on all network interfaces, commonly denoted as 0.0.0.0.

From what I can tell, I have a working docker container, listening on the correct port. When I deploy to Google Cloud Run, I receive an error:

```
> gcloud run deploy my-service --image gcr.io/my-project/my-image --project my-project --port 80
...
Deployment failed
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
```

In the Cloud Run Console and I can see that the service is configured with a `PORT` of 80 as you would expect from the `--port 80` included in the deployment command. I am having trouble figuring out why this isn't working. It seems like I've done everything right.

Does anybody have any idea what might be going wrong here?

This is what I see in the deployment log on Google Cloud:

[image]

Maybe the issue is related to the third line that says `ln -f -s /var/lib/nginx/logs /var/log/nginx`?

It looks like I'm not the only person to have this issue with this base image:

https://github.com/webdevops/Dockerfile/issues/358

I still don't know what the problem is, but it seems to effect other people trying to use this image specifically with Cloud Run.

Comment: what is with the "operation not permitted" message? The container isn't starting properly because something else seems broken. Maybe a permission thing in correlation of the docker image and cloud run prerequisites?

Comment: It just says `ln: /var/log/nginx: Operation not permitted`. I just don't understand why I would get this error on Cloud Run but not locally. It does seem like this is some sort of permissions error, not a port error.

Comment: I believe it's maybe from executing this line in `/opt/docker/provision/entrypoint.d/20-nginx.sh`: `ln -f -s /var/lib/nginx/logs /var/log/nginx`

Comment: where are these lines coming from? is this the entrypoint of the source docker image? I dont exactly know what is happening in the background here but the image wants to create a symbolic link from a location in "var/lib" to "var/log". I guess that operation is not permitted in Cloud Run. Can the Image be configured to log directly to `/var/log/nginx`?

Comment: Yes I think it's the entrypoint of the source image. This is the source image: https://dockerfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/DockerImages/dockerfiles/php-nginx.html. The line has a comment above it that says: `# Prevent startup of nginx (ubuntu 16.04 needs it)
ln -f -s /var/lib/nginx/logs /var/log/nginx`

Comment: Just found this: https://github.com/webdevops/Dockerfile/issues/358

Comment: @JohnHanley I don't think that's right. Look at the docs: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/containers#console. It says choose any port between 1 and 65535.

Comment: @JohnHanley can you explain some more details on what you mean? Besides nginx or apache, the only other option would be to use the build-in php development server to listen for requests, but this server is not designed for production. So I'm not sure what you mean by nginx being overkill. A web server is needed. How else can it be done? Maybe you did not see from my question that this is a PHP app?

Comment: That link says nothing about what we are discussing. Thank you anyway.